# Does this function similar to an "inverse primorial" already have a well-known label?

Tags: functions, notation, prime-factorization

While working with numbers of the form $p_n\#$ (the [primorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primorial)) I began to wonder about what an inverse of the "primorial" operation might be like.  I think that reusing the symbol makes some sense, so we might say something like

> $\#^{-1}(n)$ is the largest prime factor of $n$.

With this definition, we can get some simple properties:

- $(x,(\#^{-1}(x))\#)$ is the largest squarefree number which divides $x$
- $p_n=\#^{-1}(p_n\#)$ for every $n$
- $\forall z\in \Bbb Z^+,\#^{-1}(z\#)=p_{\pi(z)}$ is the largest prime not greater than $z$.

Seeing as $\pi(n)$ and $p_n$ already provide highly useful functions, it seems that this particular function has very limited usefulness.  Are there other known uses out there for this function?  Is there already a given name and/or symbol for this function?

Comment: I see that there is another brief mention of a function like this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2366111/86846 (and that is really the function I was looking for to begin with, but I paused here with a definition of a function that is more direct).